# Cut a line out of a string with Regex

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a solution for removing line 2 out of a string in C#. Of course, I could just read line by line, but with a regex, it would be much better and more elegant. As an example:

Before:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
```

After:

```
this is line 1
this is line 3
this is line 4
```

Does someone have a good hint about how to do this with Regex?
Thanks.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich That is so true!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* do it with a regular expression if you really want to:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\A(.*\n).*\n", "$1");
```

For handling platform dependent line endings:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"\A(.*{0}).*{0}", Environment.NewLine));
s = regex.Replace(s, "$1");
```

However I think it would be more clear using `string.Split` and then rejoining:

```
List<string> lines = s.Split(new string[]{ Environment.NewLine },
                             StringSplitOptions.None)
                      .ToList();
lines.RemoveAt(1);

// Note: In .NET 4.0 the ToArray call is not required.
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray());
```

I agree that the regular expression is more concise, but people who aren't familiar with regular expression syntax (and even people who are) will prefer the more explicit version.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions look very nice!

Answer (score 1):

I know you requested a regex solution, but don't shoot the messenger when I say that regular expressions are not the right tool for this job.

You could have an elegant solution by reading the file as lines, and skipping the second one:

```
string fileContents = 
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadAllLines("filepath").Where((line, index) => index != 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your regular expression to Singleline mode to disable treatment of the newline as special. Example:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^[^\r\n]*\r\n([^\r\n]*\r\n)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = r.Match(myText);
String line 2 = null;
if (m.Success) {
    line2 = m.Captures[1].Value;
    myText = substring(myText, 0, m.Captures[1].Index) +
        substring(myText, m.Captures[1].Index + m.Captures[1].Length);
}
// line2 will contain "this is line 2\r\n"
// myText will be all text except line2.
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/cpref/html/frlrfsystemtextregularexpressionsregexoptionsclasstopic.asp
 for more help.